# Objective C: My custom -init method not getting called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class that I'm deriving from UIView, and I wanted to create a -init class for it like so:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // my initializations here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Unfortunately I know for a fact that -init is not getting called. Here is how I define it in my .h:

```
-(id)init;
```

Anybody know why it's not getting called?

ADDENDUM:

I found that when I put my initialization in initWithCoder, it is run just fine. 
I added initWithFrame but that wasn't called.

This is for an object that I specified in IB.

Comment: Do you initialize the object calling init?

Comment: Do you have any UIView that you have assigned it this type and you use it in the GUI?

Answer (score 14):

There are two designated initializers for `UIViewController` and `UIView` they are `initWithCoder` called from `nib`, and `initWithFrame` called from code. `Init` is not the designated initializer for those objects.

If you want to cover both bases you can do something like this:

```
-(void)initializationCodeMethod{
    <#Initialization Code Here#>
}
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
        [self initializationCodeMethod];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
        [self initializationCodeMethod];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: One neat trick I learned from some Apple sample code: rather than having a method like initializationCodeMethod (which is easy to override by accident in a subclass) just make a static function in your c file: `static void commonInit(MyClass *self) { ... }` and call that.