# Setting up buttons in interface builder but want to call custom init method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton class. I have set up the buttons in the interface builder. I have this code:

```
#import "FriendButton.h"

@implementation FriendButton



-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    NSLog(@"init called");
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    return self;

}
```

It isn't being called though, I have set the class type to FriendButton in the interface builder. Is there a different method I need to use? I know that for custom `UITableViewCell`s one has to use `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198873/927947

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C: My custom -init method not getting called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198827/objective-c-my-custom-init-method-not-getting-called)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Apple docs:

> Objects that conform to the NSCoding protocol (including all
>   subclasses of UIView and UIViewController) are initialized using their
>   initWithCoder: method.