# initWithNavigationBarClass and UINavigationBar init methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, init, alloc

I am using `UINavigationController`'s [initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:)

to initialize an instance `UINavigationController` with a Custom Navigation Bar `MyCustomNavigationBar`.

```
[super initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyCustomNavigationBar class]
toolbarClass:nil];
```

I wish to do some setUp of `MyCustomNavigationBar` in it's initalizer -

**e.g.**

```
//  MyCustomNavigationBar.m

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But `init` is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198873/4003548 ..

Answer (score 0):

`init` is never called in the above code as it is not the *"Designated Initializer"*

[- initWithFrame:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) is the *"Designated Initializer"*

Therefore the custom `setUp` should be done here:

```
  - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self setUp];
        }
        return self;
    }
```